# How to call Swift from an Objective C project App Delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

This code is from a Swift project App delegate. It is used to help configure Stripe with a publishable key.

```
//Appdelegate.swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool 
{
//The code helps configure Stripe with a publishable key.
STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = Constants.publishableKey
...
}
```

Two errors are displayed when building the app after adding the Swift line to the Objective C App Delegate

```
//AppDelegate.h
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = Constants.publishableKey

Property 'shared' not found on object of type 'STPPaymentConfiguration'
Use of undeclared identifier 'Constants'
```

This was a similar error in compiling before `@objc` was added to the demo Swift function, MockApiClient. Should it be added elsewhere? I've tried adding `@objc` to the enum as mentioned in the answer here to no avail yet.

```
//Constants.swift 
//This is the file the original Swift app delegate accesses
import Foundation

  enum Constants {
  static let publishableKey = "pk_live_..."
  static let baseURLString = "http://54.33.123.227:1234"
  static let defaultCurrency = "usd"
  static let defaultDescription = "Receipt" //change to describe actual app & charge
  }
```

**Steps taken:**

1. Opened the Objective C project and created a bridging header
2. Created a demo class in Swift while still in the Obj C project to make sure it can be used, in this case to print from an Objective C file when the view is loaded. Specifically derived from an NSObject. Adding the override to the initializer and using the `@objc` prefix.

   ```
   //  MockApiClient.swift
   import Foundation
   class MockApiClient: NSObject
   {
   override init()
   {
   print("Initializer called in Mock API client")
   }
   @objc func executeRequest()
   {
   print("The execute request has been called in the Mock API Client")
   }
   }

   //ViewController.h
   //Prints the Swift request written in the MockApiClient the the view loads

   @implementation ViewController
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   MockApiClient *client = [MockApiClient new];
   [client executeRequest];
   }
   ```
3. Copied the `#import "ViewController.h"` import to the automatically generated `project-Bridging-Header.h` file to expose the Objective C in it to swift
4. Added the necessary Swift files to the Objective C project so that the `Constants.publishablekey` data from `Constants.swift` can be found

How can this Swift App delegate code be added to the App delegate of an Objective C project?

Edit: error when adding `@objc` to the `enum` declaration in `Constants.swift`

[image]

Comment: If STPPaymentConfiguration and Constants are Swift objects, then to be seen by Objective-C they need to be of a type that Objective-C _can_ see (i.e. classes exposed with `@objc`) and the Objective-C file needs to import the automatically generated header file (nothing to do with "adding" a header file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit: error when adding @objc to the enum declaration in Constants.swift

Swift enums used as namespace cannot be exposed to Objective-C.
You may need to use `class` to make it work both for Swift and Objective-C:

```
@objcMembers
class Constants: NSObject {
    static let publishableKey = "pk_live_..."
    static let baseURLString = "http://54.33.123.227:1234"
    static let defaultCurrency = "usd"
    static let defaultDescription = "Receipt" //change to describe actual app & charge
    
    private override init() {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After updating the `Constants.Swift` file as recommended, the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'Constants'` went away so know it seems the app is officially reading the Constant attributes. Now there is only one error of `Property 'shared' not found on object of type 'STPPaymentConfiguration'. Any ideas?
`

Comment: The `STPPaymentConfiguration` class used in the delegate was declared in `STPPaymentConfiguration.h` from the Stripe Cocoapods. How can this class further be included considering it is already written in Objective C?

Comment: As far as I checked the documentation page of Stripe, all the types, properties and methods are already marked as `@objc`. But some of them are given Objective-C names independently from Swift names. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The ability of Objective-C to see things defined in Swift depends on the automatically generated header file. This is *not* the bridging header. It is a header file buried in your derived data called *YourProject-Swift.h*. Your Objective-C *.m* file needs to `#import "YourProject-Swift.h"` (using the correct name).

Then, your Swift things need to get into that file. For that to happen, they need to be of a type that Objective-C can see at all (i.e. classes) and they need to be explicitly exposed to Objective-C with appropriate `@objc` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the response @matt. Can you please verify that the correct steps are to create a bridging header, add `#import "YourProject-Swift.h"` to Appdelegate.m, add `#import "Stripe.h"`,  to the bridging header file as it contains a .m file that has all the Stripe header files, then and `AppDelegate.h` to the bridging header file, then add the Swift line to the `Appdelegate.m` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, then adding the `@objc` prefix?

Comment: Specifically I have tried @objc enum Constants... in Constants.swift and the compiler warning is shown: '@objc' enum must declare an integer raw type

Comment: Yes, did you read what I said? I was quite clear about what Objective C can see. Did I mention enums? And I said _not_ the bridging header. Read what I actually said, please.